# Response not successful: Received status code 400 React.js Apollo GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, node.js, graphql, apollo

I have the following code and I'm getting an error when querying and I don't know why. When using GraphiQL, it queries successfully. I'm not sure if it's just a typo, or if there's something wrong with the code I have. Below I included the query, the component that calls the query, and the schema. The error I'm getting is "Response not successful: Received status code 400". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Query:

```
 import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
    
 const CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT = gql`
     mutation CreateClientAccount($name: String, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
        createClientAccount(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
            id
            auth
        }
    }
`

export { CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT };
```

Query call:

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT } from "../queries/accountQueries";

    function CreateAccount({ name, email, password }) {
        const [ createClientAccount, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT);
        
        return (
            form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                    
                createClientAccount({
                    variables: {
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }
                })
            }}>
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Schema:

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        createClientAccount: {
            type: AccountType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                return await account.createAccount({
                    name: args.name,
                    email: args.email, 
                    password: args.password
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`name` parameter in your schema is also Required | Non Nullable ->
`name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },`
```

So your mutation should be following:

```
const CREATE_CLIENT_ACCOUNT = gql`
     mutation CreateClientAccount($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
        createClientAccount(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
            id
            auth
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still getting a status 400 error, however.

Comment: Also, how did you get that error message?